# Como actualizar base de datos mysql (web / localhost)

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un desarrollo web (Angular-PHP-Mysql) pero hay zonas que no poseen internet. Bien pensé en localhost, pero ¿cómo hago para crear un botón que apretando, al reconocer wifi, actualice de forma automática la base de datos que esta en la web? No sé ni como arrancar, porque al principio tendría que preguntar web o localhost. No pretendo que me hagan el trabajo, pero si me pueden linkear ejemplos o documentación al respecto. Tendría que ser con php porque ya tengo todo el sistema con php.

Comment: Hola! Disculpa, no es clara tu pregunta. Tampoco es viable pedir recomendaciones, que no es el objetivo de este sitio. Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: "actualice de forma automática la base de datos que esta en la web?", si lo necesitas a nivel de base de datos, yo lo hice con **Base de datos compartidos**, buscalo en google y lo encontraras facilmente.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes crear un archivo php llamado conexion.php y llamarlo desde donde quieras usar la conexión de esta manera:

```
require_once 'conexion.php';
```

contenido de archivo conexión.php:

```js
<?php

function conectarse() {
    if (!($link = mysqli_connect("nombre_servidor","usuario_servidor","pass_servidor"))) {
        $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","usuario_localhost","pass_localhost");
       $link->set_charset('utf8_spanish_ci');
       
    }
    if (!mysqli_select_db("nombre_base_datos_servidor", $link )) {
        mysqli_select_db("nombre_base_datos_local", $link );
        exit();
    }
    return $link;
}
error_reporting(0);
 mysqli_close($link); 
?>
```

Comment: Las funciones de mysql están obsoletas en PHP considera leer sobre PDO o MySQLi